# Integrate doT.js template with backbone

Tags: backbone.js, dot.js

Please help me with process to integrate doT.js template in Backbone framework. Ie i need to override the backbone view with doTjs. Thanks for the help

Comment: As is, your question is very vague. Please edit it to add what difficulties you encountered in using dot.js with Backbone

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override the Backbone View. You just need to for example set your doT.js template as the View's `template` variable.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: doT.template("<your>Template</text>"),

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this);
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(data));
  }
});
```

If you want your templates to be external files you have 2 choices:

1. Use AJAX to fetch the external files and store the response in a string which you give to doT.js
2. Use [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/) or other module framework to offshore the AJAXing to them.

Comment: Hi Jakke, thanks for your response. The doT.js template is an external template in my case. How can i handle the same here.

Comment: It would be much easier for me to help, if you'd edit your question with all the relevant info. For example are you using a module framework like requirejs, where your templates are etc.

Comment: Im using backbone MVC framework for my app. currently i need to set the dot.js template as backbone view. Also the doTjs template needs be included as external file or external template.